# Track function execution with real progress bar

Tags: python-3.x, progress-bar

I have made a script for remote management of some routers, it has option to make a speed test, the speed test continues for 10 sec in both direction download/upload, when it finish it only output the info, but instead I want to show the progress of the function with some progress bar or something, like

```
function executing 
[---------->]100%
```

example bar during execution. How can I do this?

I tried few examples but all I find is fake progress bars with some time already set, I want to be real track.

If needed will post my functions

expected results like:

```
download testing
[live progress bar here] 
upload testing
[live progress bar here]
```

EDIT:

i tried this for example:

import time 
from tqdm import tqdm 
for i in tqdm(range(10)): 
....: time.sleep(3) 60%|██████ | 6/10 [00:18<00:12, 0.33 it/s]

but this takes specified times, also set time.sleep (which i dont want), my function which does the test continues for 10 sec and i want to track those exact seconds in which function is doing the work and track to progress and for example in the last second of its work bar must be like 90%, this which i tried, double the execution time, one time function executes and then time.sleep which is not helpful xD

Comment: Could you list the things you have tried and why it didn't fit your need ?

Comment: of course, i tried this for example: import time
```
from tqdm import tqdm
for i in tqdm(range(10)):
   ....:     time.sleep(3)

 60%|██████    | 6/10 [00:18<00:12,  0.33 it/s] ``` but this takes specified times, also set time.sleep (which i dont want), my function which does the test continues for 10 sec and i want to track those exact seconds in which function is doing the work and track to progress and for example in the last second of its work bar must be like 90%, this which i tried, double the execution time, one time function executes and then time.sleep which is not helpful xD

Comment: Thank for your answer. In my opinion, you should integrate this comment to your question with some formatting, this would really add value (I'm sorry I don't know the python package that would help you, but this is some advice to improve your question and get some visibility)

Comment: Thank you, actually i just joined stackoverflow today, so i am still newbie xD

Comment: Don't hesitate to edit several times your question afterwards to improve the formatting, add clarity and give examples

Comment: At some point you have to be a newbie to become more ;)